# Не могу подсоединится к MS SQL Server для импорта базы данных в mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

Собственно, заголовок говорит сам за себя. Также, прикрепляю скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD 1:

[image: варианты]

UPD 2:
[image: ODBC driver]

Comment: У вас на скриншоте написано MS Access Database,  а не Sql Server.  Проверьте настройки соединения.

Comment: Перепробовал все варианты, но ошибка не исчезает.

Comment: У вас в варинатах нет SQL Server в списке доступных баз. Скорее всего просто драйвер под него не установлен - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339

Comment: Ну или в Connection Method стоит поискать что-то другое

Comment: @PashaPash добавил upd 2, вроде бы всё есть.

Comment: перебирайте варианты в  Connection Method - от него зависит список вариантов в DBs. скорее всего SQL Server будет доступен при выборе ODBC Native

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, для успешного подключения необходимо добавить свой connection:
Шаг 1:

Open ODBC Administrator -

[image: Open ODBC Administrator]

Шаг 2:

Добавляем SQL server connection и настраиваем его под себя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и всё.